# Why in "docker logs" i can`t get my logs from monolog?

Tags: php, docker, logging, stdout, monolog

in `docker logs` i see only nginx messages, but not from monolog

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iRjV.png

I tried send some message to stdout stream and see it in `docker logs`

```
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('MyTestName');
$handler = new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::DEBUG);
$logger->pushHandler($handler);
$logger->error('My test error message');
```

in `docker logs` will be my error message

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini, add the following lines:

```html
log_errors = On
error_log = /dev/stderr
```

Now you'll be able to see any PHP error logs:

```html
docker logs -f php_container
```

Comment: Hm... but this will be logs from php, but not my custom) And yes, it`s already done